# Confusion about using switchMap twice in RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
import { fromEvent, switchMap, interval, take, map, tap } from 'rxjs';

const clicksA = fromEvent(document.getElementById('A'), 'click');
const resultA = clicksA.pipe(
  tap(()=>console.log('------ START [Button A] ------')),
  switchMap(() => interval(500).pipe(take(2),map((i)=>`A ${i}`))),
  tap((A)=>console.log(A))
);
resultA.subscribe();

const clicksAB = fromEvent(document.getElementById('AB'), 'click');
const resultAB = clicksAB.pipe(
  tap(()=>console.log('------ START [Button A+B] ------')),
  switchMap(() => interval(500).pipe(take(2),map((i)=>`A ${i}`))),
  tap((A)=>console.log(A)),
  switchMap(() => interval(500).pipe(take(2),map((i)=>`B ${i}`))),
  tap((B)=>console.log(B))
);
resultAB.subscribe();
```

When I use only one `switchMap`,The `console` looks like this:

```
------ START [Button A] ------
------ START [Button A] ------
A 0
------ START [Button A] ------
A 0
A 1
```

When I use only two `switchMap`,the `console` looks like this

```
------ START [Button A+B] ------
------ START [Button A+B] ------
A 0
------ START [Button A+B] ------
B 0  <----- Look at this ！！！
A 0
A 1
B 0
B 1
```

RxJS [`switchMap` description](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap#description):

> When a new inner Observable is emitted, switchMap stops emitting items from the earlier-emitted inner Observable and begins emitting items from the new one. It continues to behave like this for subsequent inner Observables.

When I send a new Observable before the second switchMap, why does B message appear in the console?

```
I hope there's no such message
B 0  <----- Look at this ！！！
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fezvu8?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.ts)

Comment: It is hard to grasp what is happening in your code. Try simplifying it so you get more help.

Comment: **2 SwitchMaps without click-interruption**: The emission of A1 will cancel the first attempt to emit B0 resp. it triggers a re-subscription in the second switchMap and therefore delays the emisson of B0 by another 500ms. **2 SwitchMaps with interruption by click**: If you click the button after A0 was emitted, then the first attempt to emit A1 is cancelled and therefore there is no A-event that stops B0 from being emitted. **Important to know**: Entering the first switchMap does **not** stop the second switchMap from emitting values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @kellermat Thank you for your answer. **Important to know**: Entering the first switchMap does not stop the second switchMap from emitting values.  I understand. But is this reasonable? This is a stream.Cut off upstream and start a new stream.  The second SwitchMaps Message should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { fromEvent, switchMap, interval, take, map, tap } from 'rxjs';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = clicks.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('------ CLICK START ------')),
  switchMap(() =>
    interval(500).pipe(
      take(2),
      map((i) => `A ${i}`),
      tap((A) => console.log(A)),
      switchMap(() =>
        interval(500).pipe(
          take(2),
          map((i) => `B ${i}`),
          tap((B) => console.log(B))
        )
      ),
    )
  ),
  
);
result.subscribe();
```

Nesting the two SwitchMaps solves the problem!

@kellermat Thank you again for your answer!